# Stop clang-format from splitting elements onto multiple lines in VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang-format

When I type a vector into VS Code using clang-format as the auto-formatter it splits each element onto it's own line like so:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v = {1,
                     2,
                     3,
                     4,
                     5};
}
```

**What I would like** is for it to remain like this:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
}
```

I have looked through all of the clang-format settings but cannot find anything that changes this.

Comment: what is your clang-format file. Can you share that? Also, please mention the clang-format version you are using

Comment: I think it could be a combination of ColumnLimit and BinPackArguments = false.

Comment: You can try online at https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/ - this is trial and error but still halfway comfortable.

Comment: Where do I find the clang-format file?

Comment: @Andy Change the style to something else ( like llvm, mozilla) in the extension settings and see if that is okay for you. .clang-format file is in the top directory of the code.

Comment: *"I have looked through all of the clang-format settings but cannot find anything that changes this."* where were you going to put those settings if you don't have a clang-format file ?

Comment: In VS Code itself (File, Preferences, Settings) it allows me to edit lots of settings for clang-format

Comment: The only clang-format file I can see is in the root directory under usr/bin but I can't seem to view it with vim or cat

Answer (score 1):

> AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine (bool)
>
> If a function call or braced initializer list doesn’t fit on a line, allow putting all arguments onto the next line, even if BinPackArguments is false.

This should be true.

Also increase `ColumnLimit`

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html